# new to ruby, finding a value in a nested hash

Tags: ruby

I can't figure out how to get the value of @responseType from this nested hash.

```
{
  "mgmtResponse": {
    "@responseType": "operation"}}
```

Comment: If `h` is your hash, `g = h[:mgmtResponse] #=> {:@responseType=>"operation"}`, so you want `g[:@responseType] #=> "operation"`, which is the same as  `h[:mgmtResponse][:@responseType]`. Incidentally, it's helpful to assign a variable to each input in examples (e.g., `h = { "mgmtResponse": {  "@responseType": "operation"}}`). That way readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 3):

While @tadman is strictly correct, it's safer to use the new ruby 2.3 dig function. The big difference is that if the key doesn't exist, dig will return nil, whereas the brackets notation would throw `` NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass ``. To use dig, you would use `hash.dig("mgmtResponse", "@responseType")`.

The syntax for the hash which you used in the question is a little strange and awkward in that it appears that the keys are strings (because they are surrounded in quotes) but because you use the `:` notation ruby converts them to symbols. So on your hash `hash.dig(:mgmtResponse, :@responseType)` will work and `hash.dig("mgmtResponse", "@responseType")` will be nil, because those *string* keys do not exist. If you use the `=>` notation instead of the `:` notation, then `hash.dig("mgmtResponse", "@responseType")` will exists and `hash.dig(:mgmtResponse, :@responseType)` will be `nil`.

So what you are looking for is this:

```
hash = {
  "mgmtResponse" => {
    "@responseType" => "operation"
  }
}

hash.dig("mgmtResponse", "@responseType") #=> "operation"
```

or if you want to use your (confusing) hash syntax then:

```
hash = {
  "mgmtResponse": {
    "@responseType": "operation"
  }
}

hash.dig(:mgmtResponse, :@responseType) #=> "operation"
```

Comment: `hash.dig("mgmtResponse", "@responseType") #=> nil` when I try?

Comment: Using `{"key": "value}` converts the key to a symbol! That's why!

Answer (score 1):

Straight up traversal:

```
hash['mgmtResponse']['@responseType']
```

You can use the `[]` approach to arrays, hashes, even strings:

```
"test"[2]
# => "s"
```